# How to remove 750Hz sinusoidal background from audio using FIR filter?

Tags: matlab, finite-impulse-response

Kindly help me to design a FIR filter for eliminating the 750 Hz sinusoidal beep from audio. I shall be thankful to you

Comment: you have a matlab tag, do you have the signal processing toolbox.

Comment: Can you provide more information about how we can help you? Which parts of the process do you need help with: theory, design, implementation?

Comment: Thank you so much for rapid response. actually i want to implement the FIR filter in MATLAB. and i want to calculate the filter coeffiecients manually. but i dont know where to start. i just know that i have to supress the 750HZ frequency. plz help